# could not go to admin page in wordpress if users role no administrator

Tags: wordpress

i have problem with my wordpress admin.
when i use account with the role is vendor and go to: mywebsite.com/wp-admin it auto redirect to mywebsite.com, but when i use account is admin1 with the role is work well(direct to mywebsite.com/wp-admin)
before it was working well i have deactivated and reactive my plugin
and i use function : delete_option('myplugin_default_data_installed'); to remove my plugin when i deactivate my plugin
i don't know how to fix it. i know if i remove delete_option() in my plugin it's work well, but know i want to fix in my database
any one can help me
thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do using hooks.put this code in functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );

function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && 
       ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.
Thanks.